# 0 seconds engagement time for GTM and GA4

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have essentially a blog page that my users will load, read and close.

So GA and GTM are showing the engagement as 0.

I have implemented scrolling events that I was hoping would update the engagment parameter, but they're not.
Is there a way that I can make the scroll events trigger an update in engagement time?

[image: This user was on the page for 54 seconds, but it shows 0 seconds engagement]